# Code snippet for counting the number of digits in string, how to write it to work?

Tags: javascript

Code snippet for counting the number of digits in string, how to write it to work?

```js
const str = "192.168.5.0"
const digits = [...str].reduce((a, char) => char === /\d/.test(char) ? ++a : a, 0);

console.log(digits);
```

Comment: remove the `char === ` as `.test()` will return a boolean for you

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize that the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) converts true to 1 and false to 0. Just convert the boolean returned by `test()` to number this way, and add the result to the counter in `reduce()`. 1 will be added when the charatcter is a digit and 0 if it's not.

```js
const str = "192.168.5.0"
const digits = [...str].reduce((n, char) => n + +/\d/.test(char), 0);

console.log(digits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could achieve this by using regex:

```js
const str = '1192.168.5.0';
const matches = [...str.matchAll(/\d/g)];

console.log(matches.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
const str = '1192.168.5.0';

let count = 0;
for (let ch of str) ch >= "0" && ch <= "9" && count++;

console.log(count);
```